# Проксирование данных от API Яндекс через NGINX Reverse Proxy на внутренний сервер

Tags: nginx, яндекс-карта-api

Есть задача, получать данные от API Яндекс внутренним сервером через nginx reverse proxy. Данные который будет получать сервер это местоположения транспорта (общественного). Сейчас настройка проксирования к этому серверу выглядит так:

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        server_name     example.ru;

        ssl_certificate         /etc/nginx/ssl/example.ru/example.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key     /etc/nginx/ssl/example.ru/example.key;

        access_log      /var/log/nginx/example.ru/example.ru_access.log main;
        error_log       /var/log/nginx/example.ru/example.ru_error.log;

        location / {
                proxy_pass      http://172.16.10.130;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_connect_timeout 1000;
                proxy_send_timeout 1000;
                proxy_read_timeout 1000;
                send_timeout 1000;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
                root /var/www/errors;
        }

}
```

Сервер будет принимать запросы на определенном порту (прим. 8093). Еще программист мне дал пример формата http get-запроса: GET [http://extjams.maps.yandex.net/mtr_collect/1.x/?{п..](http://extjams.maps.yandex.net/mtr_collect/1.x/?%7B%D0%BF..). URL}
Честно, в google смотрел но развернутого ответа не нашел.
Поэтому и вопрос, как проксировать данные API?

Может вот вот такое подойдет для решения моего вопроса?

```
location /api {
    proxy_pass  http://172.16.10.130:8091;
    proxy_set_header    Host        $host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP   $remote_addr;
}
```

Comment: Попахивает желанием нарушить лицензионное соглашение.

Comment: Но вообще вопрос непонятен. Приведённый конфиг не имеет никакого отношения к проксированию апи яндекса

Comment: Я знаю что никакого отнощения конфиг не имеет. Я имею ввиду как мне данные от API яндекс отправить на этот же сервер по другому порту.

Comment: Стало ещё более непонятно чего вы зотите

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос был решен следующим образом.

Пообщавшись с разработчиками, стала понятна схему того как должно работать:

- система отправляет данные на определенный URL;
- запрос на nginx проксируется на порт;
- консольное приложением слушаю порт и считывает данные;
- (опционально) отправляет что-нибудь в ответ.

Добавил в конфиг еще один location, в котором utl проксируется на определенный порт:

```
location /GisTransport/SetITSData {
     proxy_pass   https://172.16.10.130:8093;
     proxy_set_header Host             $host;
     proxy_set_header X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

Если кто-то что-то не понял, скажу что и я не знаю всех нюансов так как разработками занимается другой отдел и развернутой информации никто не дает.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).